# What does the phrase "moody, rock-inflected soundtrack" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "moody, rock-inflected soundtrack" in the following sentence:

> In the game meet the neighbors, and tend to gardens—all while
>   listening to its beautifully moody, rock-inflected soundtrack.

The sentence is from an offline description of a game.

Comment: What research have you done?  Do you understand what "moody" and "soundtrack" mean?

Comment: The soundtrack means the music that is played throughout the game. I don't know the meaning of the word "moody".

Comment: @curious please check the definition here - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moody

Comment: Also, the definition of [**inflected**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inflected): influenced.